# Count records between timespan of an hour

Tags: sql, datetime

I am trying to count all records that are between a given timespan of an hour.

**Table:** History

**Columns:**

```
Name (varchar), 
StartTime (datetime), 
EndTime (datetime)

Date, hour, count of names
17-03 - 10 - 6
17-03 - 11 - 12
```

Can someone please help me write a query for this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Its an Oracle database. A single record can be in multiple hours therefore need to be count for every hour if its active between StartTime and EndTime.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please add to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use check range of date as below. If you need count based on `Name` column use below query:

```
select Name, count(1) from history
where StartTime >= 'startdate' and EndTime <= 'enddate'
group by Name;
```

If you need overall count use this:

```
select count(1) from history
where StartTime >= 'startdate' and EndTime <= 'enddate';
```